# How to get/set information in an SQL database via internet connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, web-services, mobile

I'm currently creating an SQL database that will eventually be accessed by web applications, both mobile and desktop platforms. 
Setting up the SQL database is easy. 
What I'm currently having trouble with is how I'm going to allow clients to access to information in the database without having direct access to the database, for security purposes.

For example, let's say I have a list of employees, and I'm creating employee profiles for a mobile application. I would like for the mobile application to be able to use a function such as get(employee_name), which will call the database and retrieve the information about the employee in the form of a JSON.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: By making a HTTP request to your server which will fetch the data from the db.

Comment: To broad of a question. You have to be more specific. You can write an application that connects to a database that reads and writes data. You can create a layer between the application and the database where said layer is a service that is reading and writing data on behalf of the client. One example may be a Wordpress that is hosted on a server where MySQL is hosted. Wordpress is already on the network and therefore can connect to the database to read and write data securely.

Comment: @Fastidious I was leaning more towards creating a layer between the client and the database, almost like an API. Let's say I'm on Android, and I click on a row with an employees name. What is my best bet for getting that information from the database using an extra layer that is hosted on the same machine that the SQL server is hosted on?

Comment: I'm a database guy myself. It's good to have extra layers for security purposes whether that's your application communicating via API or like someone mentioned, making HTTP requests to fetch the data. Creating your own custom API would be a little more complicated versus other methods if you're new to programming. Either way, that layer doesn't have to live on the same machine as the data. It can live on the same network as the data where the network can be a cluster or federation of many machines.

Comment: @fastidious Alright, thanks! I've been using a java servlet to take in the HTTP requests, but how would I even go about writing an API for it? I want other people to use this database, but I'm not sure where to start for an API in terms of platform.

Answer (score 0):

To see a very nice solution on using JSON on sql server tables please look at Phil Factors article Consuming JSON Strings in SQL Server at:

```
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/
```